# How can I find all deprecations in pandas between two versions?

Tags: python, pandas

My current project is using pandas version 0.22.

I wish to upgrade it to the latest version (say, 1.4.2), but I'm afraid that some code in my project won't work properly after the upgrade.

I searched in the [changes log](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#deprecations) for the deprecation list, but it does not provide me a "diff" between the two versions.

Is there a way to find the entire deprecations list between the two versions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in deprecation, they usually occur while incrementing Major or Minor Version i.e. from 0.x to 1.0 or 1.2.x to 1.3.0 for example.

Deprecations are avoided during patch increment (e.g. 1.2.2 to 1.2.3).
With one exception being 1.0.1. So you could easily get all deprecations from the page you linked.

If you're interested in all changes between the versions, you can compare their tags in git: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/compare/v0.22.0...v1.4.2
That's a lot though...